# How to simply setup Mac OS X on ESXi 5.x+?

Tags: macos, esxi

The simplest way to setup a Mac OS X on ESXi 5.x+?

On all supported hardware.

Comment: This is similar to "Hackintosh" questions and we consider these to be [off topic](http://meta.superuser.com/a/1473/22317).

Comment: How about now...

Comment: No Apple hardware = TOS violation. It's *that* easy. That's also why VMware restricts it like that (see answer by skub). They don't care, but Apple does.

Comment: Not quite... Still have the non-standard hardware on there.

Comment: http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/MacOSX_10_7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only ESXi 5 supports OS X as a host operating system and *only* on Apple branded servers. Beyond that, it's against the TOS to run OS X on any non-Apple branded hardware.

See requirements [here](http://blogs.vmware.com/guestosguide/2011/08/apple-mac-os-x-server.html).

Comment: What about all the people that do not have Apple branded servers?

Comment: Those people will have to restate their questions or look for answers elsewhere...